# "Напитанность поисками духовного идеала" - возможно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> А художники Возрождения, как никакие другие художники, напитанные
>   поисками духовного идеала, сумели каждый по-своему воспеть славу
>   Господу, запечатлеть любовь и красоту этого мира.

ПыСы. Это наш общий приз, и Инга так считает.

> На церемонии награждения Премии «Бродский на Искье – Путешественник
>   без границ», прошедшей на вилле режиссера Лукино Висконти LA
>   COLOMBAIA, авторские статуэтки работы скульптора Владимира Амодео были
>   вручены актрисе и писательнице Инге Ильм, солистке Большого театра
>   Елене Зеленской (сопрано) и кинорежиссеру Татьяне Данильянц.
>
> Уже семь лет Искья становится местом встречи российской и итальянской
>   культур, где известные деятели искусства, журналисты, представители
>   бизнеса отдают дань уважения величайшим талантам, связанным с этой
>   землей, – поэту Иосифу Бродскому и режиссеру Лукино Висконти. В этом
>   году Премия «Бродский на Искье – Путешественник без границ» оказалась
>   с «женским лицом» – награда за вклад в развитие российско-итальянские
>   культурные отношения получили исключительно представительницы
>   прекрасного пола.
>
> Актриса Инга Ильм, которую помнят все российские зрители по известному
>   детскому фильму «Приключения Петрова и Васечкина, обыкновенные и
>   невероятные» (1983), с некоторых пор живет в столице Италии, в Риме.
>
> Инга не только актриса театра и кино, но и профессиональный историк
>   искусства – в этом году она стала автором книги «Моя Италия», которая
>   скоро появится на полках книжных магазинов.
>
> Инга рассказала о своей жизни в Италии, приглашая читателей в
>   увлекательное путешествие по трем городам – Риму, Неаполю и Флоренции.

[источник](http://vasechkin.ru/stat.php?id_file=167)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал заменить "напитанные" на "влекомые".

Можно даже "одержимые".

И тогда, как мне кажется, предложение заиграет.

Comment: Michael_1812, автор благодарит за подсказку *влекомые*. )))

Comment: Спасибо. И возникает следующий вопрос. Как лучше: "влекомые поисками" или "влекомые поиском"? Моя рука написала бы "влекомые поиском", но у меня нет внятного объяснения почему.

Answer (score 2):

*А художники Возрождения, как никакие другие художники, напитанные поисками духовного идеала, сумели каждый по-своему воспеть славу Господу, запечатлеть любовь и красоту этого мира*.

"Напитанные поисками" мне не нравится. Нужно бы поправить: томимые жаждой духовного идеала,
погружённые в поиски духовного идеала, захваченные поисками дух. идеала и др.

И повтор **художники - художники** не нравится. Художники можно заменить на "мастера кисти", "творцы" и т. д.

Comment: Люсенька, спасибо! И сюда гляньте: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448496/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85

Answer (score 2):

Мне нравится ответ Людмилы, но хочется добавить, что фраза "напитанные поисками духовного идеала" относится то ли к "художникам Возрождения", то ли "к другим художникам".

Поэтому во  избежание недопонимания предложение, может быть,  придётся перестроить.

*А [вдохновлённые?] поисками духовного идеала художники Возрождения, как никакие другие художники, сумели каждый по-своему воспеть славу Господу, запечатлеть любовь и красоту этого мира.*

Answer (score 1):

А художники Возрождения, **как никто из художников, поглощенных поисками духовного идеала,** сумели каждый по-своему воспеть славу Господу, запечатлеть любовь и красоту этого мира.

В предложенном тесте не просматривается тесная связь выделенного фрагмента.

Comment: А, Шарончик, мы должны по возможности сохранять авторскую индивидуальность; я щас все ответы ей перешлю (уже имя не таю -  Инга Ильм). Пусть выбирает, кто ей лучшее помог. )))

Comment: Да, я, конечно, в курсе, что надо сохранять. Кстати, я повтор "художников" оставила, но хотя бы форма немного изменилась. А вот замена вида  "мастера кисти" мне кажется искусственной

Comment: Ну да, это предложено автору, но и только. Я ей сказала: пиши как говоришь (можно посмотреть ея ролики - где интервью берут; актриса же, речь прекрасная), а мы конвертируем в письмо. Но с лексикой надо очень бережно; к пунктуации, ввиду непонимания, она равнодушна.