# Что делать с пунктуацией при наслаивающихся уточнениях?

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

> Этот католический храм – Санта-Мария-сопра-Минерва (что означает
>   приблизительно следующее: храм святой Марии над храмом Минервы), один
>   из немногих в Риме, – готический.

Comment: Содержание текста неясное. Из Интернета: "Принято считать, что Санта-Мария-сопра-Минерва является единственным образцом готического христианского сооружения в Риме из дошедших до наших дней".http://tisamsebegid.ru/rim/santa-mariya-sopra-minerva Или еще: "Это единственный оригинальный пример средневекового готического стиля в Риме (в римских церквях преобладает стиль барокко)." Или: Santa Maria Sopra Minerva: Единственная готическая церковь в Риме.

Comment: Поэтому возникают вопросы: Это единственный христианский готический храм или единственный готический храм?  И всё-таки единственный или один из немногих? И к чему относится "один из немногих"? В этой фразе, кроме хорошего стиля,  нужна ещё историческая точность. Нужно понять и что сказал автор,  и как это соотносится с действительными фактами

Comment: Всё, всё полетит автору - хай маэтца.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один ум хорошо, а два лучше. Я бы посоветовала Вам, Галя, предложить автору упростить конструкцию, совместив варианты Екатерины и shampar:

*Этот католический храм Санта-Мария-сопра-Минерва (буквально  «Святая Мария над Минервой») - один из немногих готических храмов в Риме.*

Если невозможно, то так:

*Этот католический храм Санта-Мария-сопра-Минерва (что означает "Святая Мария над  Минервой") один из немногих в Риме – готический.*

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, конструкцию следует упростить:

Этот католический храм Санта-Мария-сопра-Минерва (что означает приблизительно следующее: храм святой Марии над храмом Минервы) -  один из немногих готических храмов в Риме.

Answer (score 2):

В этой фразе *храм Санта-Мария-сопра-Минерва* означает *храм святой Марии над храмом Минервы*. Много повторов, и если пояснять, то не очевидное: храм Санта-Мария-сопра-Минерва*, где *сопра* — *над*, и это не приблизительно, и/или давать перевод с латиницы.

> Этот католический храм, Santa Maria sopra Minerva (т. е. «Святая Мария
>   над Минервой»), — один из немногих в Риме — готический.